# Django on Apache with Nginx writing permissions

Tags: django, apache, nginx

I've set up Django with Apache2 + mod_wsgi. The static Files are served by Nginx. Apache is running on Port 81 and nginx on Port 80.

my settings are like this:
    MEDIA_ROOT = 'http://localhost/media/'
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http://localhost/media/'

Everything looks fine. At https://localhost:81/admin I can see the Django Admin Site with its static files.

I created a new app with this model:
    class Song(models.Model):
    song = models.FileField(upload_to='songs')

When I try to upload a file over the admin site i get following error.

OSError at /admin/player/song/add/

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/http:'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:81/admin/player/song/add/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     OSError
Exception Value:

How do I allow apache to apply changes to nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your `MEDIA_ROOT` to a url. I think it should be set to a physical location, I think the same goes for the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`. I would try change

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Projects/my_project/media/'  # assuming linux
```

and

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = PROJECT_URL + '/media/admin'
```

You'll also have to set permissions to the media folder. I think you need to give `www-data` write permissions.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. The problem was in fact the MEDIA_ROOT (stupid noob mistake). I changed the MEDIA_ROOT to the absolute path and I changed my stettup. Nginx acts as a reverseproxy now so that my ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is just /media/ instead of localhost/media. That seems more flexible and more common.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please Tick the answer to show that the answer had been solved.